Using xcode in CI/CD Google Platform
Im trying to build a CI/CD for flutter development. I'm making use of Google Cloud Cloud Build.
I already have all the setup of the Cloud Build done (with trigger), I'm using cloudbuild.yaml in order to configure the CI/CD.
I was able to build and distribute the android image.
However I'm having problems building and archiving the IOS image.
As far as I understand to build the IOS I always need XCode. I couldn't find a working docker image to make this build since docker is linux based.
What is the best solution to approach this? Since I think that with all the limitations of cloud build is not possible.
I saw something about virtualizing a macos and then use cloud build to run commands inside that vm, is that possible?
I tried multiple images. I also trying to create an docker image able to do this operation but couldn't make any xcode commands.
